# Dart drag & drop div

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm working on drag and drop div and I have the following code:

```
 void init() {


    ...
    baseWindowTitleDiv.on.mouseDown.add((MouseEvent event) => saveWindowXY(event));
    baseWindowTitleDiv.on.mouseUp.add((MouseEvent event) => stopMoveEvent(event));
    ...        
  }
  void saveWindowXY(MouseEvent event) {
    ...

    document.on.mouseMove.add((MouseEvent event) => runMoveEvent(event));

  }

  void stopMoveEvent(MouseEvent event) {
    print('stopMoveEvent call');    
    document.on.mouseMove.remove((MouseEvent event) => runMoveEvent(event));//does not work!    
  }

  void runMoveEvent(MouseEvent event) {
    ...
  }
```

I do not understand how can I remove listener from document.on.mouseMove

Full code is here - https://gist.github.com/OZKA/5795352

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do here. If you want to drag and drop a div you can use this [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://edu.makery.ch/projects/dart-html5-drag-and-drop/) library.

Comment: I do not understand why the code "document.on.mouseMove.remove ((MouseEvent event) => runMoveEvent (event));" does not work and does not remove the function runMoveEvent from document mouse move event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you'd need to have a handle to the event that you added, and use that to remove it later, for example:

```
var myEvent = (MouseEvent event) => runMoveEvent(event); // store the function in a variable.

void init() {
  document.on.mouseMove.add(myEvent); // refer to the function by name
}


void stopMoveEvent(MouseEvent event) {
  document.on.mouseMove.remove(myEvent); // remove the same function.
}

void runMoveEvent(event) { ... }
```

What you're doing in your code is adding one anonymous function, and removing a different anonymous function.   I think that http://dartbug.com/144 (tagged WontFix) probably provides more details about why this doesn't work.